# Countably close topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, first-countable

Does every uncountable topological space has a different and mutually "countably close" space?

Define "countably close" space $S$ with respect to another space $S'$ both on the same set iff the difference between any open set $U\in S$ and some open set $V\in S'$ is countable $|U\setminus V|\leq\aleph_0$

I tried disproving the negation by taking some space and some open set from any other so that their difference is uncountable but still couldn't get it.

Comment: As @RobArthan says, the answer is no. However, if you replace difference $U\setminus V$ with symmetric difference $U\Delta V$, the answer is yes, with $|U\Delta V|\leqslant 1$.

Comment: @jwhite: I think I see what you mean: you start with the cocountable topology,  pick some point $x$ and then require non-empty open sets to include $x$, giving a coarser topology that is countably close to the original.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about symmetric differences rather than differences $U\setminus V$. Let $(X,\tau)$ be an infinite topological space.

Case $1$: $\tau$ is the discrete topology and fix $x\in X$. Let $\sigma_1$ consists of those $U\subset X$ such that $x\notin U$. Let $\sigma_2$ consist of those $U\subset X$ such that $X\setminus U$ is finite. Let $\tau'=\sigma_1\cup \sigma_2$. Then one easily checks that $\tau'$ is a topology.Any member of $\tau'$ is in $\tau$, because everything is in $\tau$. Any member of $\tau$ is at most one point away from being in $\tau'$. Essentially what we've done is taken a topology with no non-isolated points and made a topology with exactly one isolated point.

Case $2$: $\tau$ is not the discrete topology. Then there exists $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}$ is not open. Create a new topology $$\tau'=\tau\cup \{A\cup \{x\}:A\in \tau\}.$$ One easily checks that this is a topology. Every $\tau$-open set is $\tau'$ open. Every $\tau'$ open set is at most one point away from a $\tau$-open set. Essentially what we've done is isolate a non-isolated point.

Comment: Seems simple, regarding the second case wouldn't $\tau'=\{A\cup\{x\}:A\in\tau\}$ also work?

Comment: I think that would work if you also throw in $\varnothing$, otherwise it isn't a topology. However, I chose $\tau'$ because it is in some sense less of a departure from the original topology. For example, I think that if $\tau$ is Hausdorff, my $\tau'$ will be. But $\{\varnothing\}\cup \{A\cup \{x\}:A\in \tau\}$ isn't, because every $y\neq x$ is only contained in open sets that also contain $x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to verify that for any topological space $G$ there are some other topologies which make them countably close to each other, if not then by such assumption it would happen that the axioms of any such topology aren't preserved.

Assume by negation that for $G$ there are no different topologies which are countably close, then take another topological space $G'$  and suppose it's countably close to $G$, it must appear that one of the axioms don't hold.

Each of the open sets $U_1, U_2\subset G'$ are countably close to open sets $V_1, V_2\subset G$ and their union must also be countably close, indeed $\big|(U_1\cup U_2)\vartriangle (V_1\cup V_2)\big|\leq \big|(U_1\vartriangle U_2)\cup(V_1\vartriangle V_2)\big|\leq\aleph_0$

Same thing can be said about the intersection again countably close, hence the axioms of a topology are preserved meaning that there must be countably close topological space $G'$ and the initial assumption is refuted.

**tl;dr** for any topological space $G_{\tau}=(G, \tau)$ "deform" the topology $\tau$ by removing or adding countably many elements from each set $V\in\tau$ turning it into a new topology $\tau'$ and it's axioms will still be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The [cocountable topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) provides a counter-example. In this topology a set is open iff it is *cocountable*, i.e., its complement is countable. Removing a countable set from a cocountable subset of an uncountable set gives you a cocountable set, so a topology that is countably close to the cocountable topology must be the same as the cocountable topology.

[EDIT]
The above was based on a possible misunderstanding that $V \subseteq U$ was required in the original question. I will revisit the answer.

Comment: But a cocountable uncountable topological space $G$ can be compared with another Lindelöf space $G′$ which by definition can only include a countable amount of countable open sets whereas all the others are uncountable open sets and for each such $V\subset G′$ can be found an uncountable open set $U\subset G$ so that $V\setminus U$ is countable. Without requiring $G′$ to carry the cocountable topology.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The cocountable topology on an uncountable set has no countable open sets apart from the empty set. What is your $G'$? If its open sets are obtained from those of the cocountable topology $G$ by removing countably many elements, then those open sets are already open in $G'$ and $G' = G$.

Comment: You are actually right but only partially, take the Euclidean line with the standard (Euclidean) topology so that it is also cocountable, and another (also cocountable) topology on the Sorgenfrey line on the basis of half-open intervals. Notice that both are cocountable but still have different topologies (open and half-open intervals) and yet are countably close to each other.

Comment: This example is not so good but what's I'm trying to say is a cocountable topology can have a countably close topology and yet a different one so that all of it's open sets are still countably close but different.

Comment: A better example is a topology on the irrational numbers where open intervals (of the irrational numbers) form the base, compare that to the Sorgenfrey line restricted to the irrational numbers (half-open intervals of the irrational numbers). The first one is cocountable, both are countably close to each other but have different topologies.